# Issue with typing object TypeScript - when using a predefined type with null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following `type`.

```
type Team = 'liverpool' | 'manUtd' | 'arsenal' | null;
```

I then have the following object.

```
const teams: Record<Team, JSX.Element> = {
  liverpool: <Liverpool />,
  manUtd: <ManU />,
  arsenal: <Arsenal />,
};
```

If I use `teams` as the first part of the `Record` I see the following error:

```
Type 'Team' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.ts(2344)
```

If I use `Record<string, JSX.Element>` it works fine.

Comment: `null` cannot be used as a key. Why do you need `null` in your type definition?

Comment: thanks @georg elsewhere in the app it can be null, as it does not always exist :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Record<NonNullable<Team>, JSX.Element>`

Let me know if this helps. this error appears because null is not a valid javascript object key type.

Comment: yeah, not a clue either. I actually thought my upvote wasn't working, and that there was a bug with SO :-D I will give you the green tick when I can anyway, cheers

Answer (score 1):

The type for `Record` is `Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T>`.

So the first type you provide to the `Record` must be either `string`, `number` or `symbol`. You can't assign `null` to it so your `Team` type does not satisfy the constraint. You should remove `null` from your `Team` type and it'll work like a charm.

Comment: Indeed, `team: null` doesn't make any sense.